# How to Ignore a specific route logging using Fastify in NestJs?

Tags: node.js, logging, nestjs, fastify

I want to ignore or change the logLevel of a route in my NestJs application using Fastify.

This is how I do it normally in Fastify application. Here I am changing the `/health` route `logLevel` to `error` so that it will only log when there is an error in health.

```
server.get('/health', { logLevel: 'error' }, async (request, reply) => {
    if (mongoose.connection.readyState === 1) {
        reply.code(200).send()
    } else {
        reply.code(500).send()
    }
})
```

But This is my health controller in NestJs

```
@Get('health')
getHealth(): string {
  return this.appService.getHealth()
}
```

And main.ts file.

```
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
        AppModule,
        new FastifyAdapter({
            logger: true
        }),
    )
```

I don't want to log the health route only and not the routes.

Please help in this regards.

Comment: did you find a solve?

Comment: @BinaryShrub yup. I posted the solution which worked for us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ignore/silent a specific route workaround in NestJS using Fastify. 
We can use Fastify hook `onRoute` and change the log level for that route. 
For example ignoring health route.

```
import fastify from 'fastify'


const fastifyInstance = fastify()
fastifyInstance.addHook('onRoute', opts => {
        if (opts.path === '/health') {
            opts.logLevel = 'silent'
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If one is willing to use [`nestjs-pino`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-pino) can use something like this:

```
LoggerModule.forRoot({
    pinoHttp: {
        transport:
            process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
                ? { target: 'pino-pretty', options: { singleLine: true } }
                : null,
        customProps: () => ({ context: 'HTTP' }),
        autoLogging: {
            ignore: (req) => {
                return ['/health/ping', '/swagger'].some((e) => req.originalUrl.includes(e))
            },
        },
    },
}),
```